# how to save data of my form in three different entities according to the option i select

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am a new in using play framework ,i wish to send data of my form in three different entities according to the option i select .your help will be appreciated.

```
@main("Add form"){
   @if(flash.containsKey("Success")){
       @flash.get("success");
   }
   @if(flash.containsKey("error")){
       @flash.get("error");
   }
    <form action="@routes.Application.saveAirtel()" method="post">
        Phone number :<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" class="form-control"><br />
            <select type="text" name="user" class="form-control"> <option>A</option>
                <option>B</option>
                <option>C</option></select>

        <button type="submit">Save aitel</button </form>}
```

*This is my Model:*

@Entity
public class Customer_one extends Model {

```
@Id
public Long id;

@Required
public int phoneNumber;

@Required
public String user ;


java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();

public static Finder<Long, Customer_one> find = new Finder(Long.class, Customer_one.class);

public static String save(Customer_one customer) {
    try {
        Customer_one customer1 = new Customer_one();

        customer1.user = customer.user;

        customer1.save();
        return Message.saveSuccess;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return Message.saveError;
    }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
public static Result sell_airtime() {


    Form<Customer_one> formData_one = Form.form(Customer_one.class).bindFromRequest();

   if (selectedOption = A){

  Do something ....


  }
  }
```

Comment: Please format your post properly and also state the real problem - do you need guidance? Do you have any errors - compile/runtime?

Comment: not i don't have an error , what i what is to get refference of selected option ,so that if A is selected  or B ,i can do s.thing in my controller. briefly ,i want to save data according to selected option value

Comment: What i am really unable is to get id references of html select option in java (controller)

Comment: What is `formData_one` in your controller containing? Only the `phoneNumber`?

Comment: not only phoneNumber , also i have ,firstName and lastName

Comment: See if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Your Twirl template needs some corrections:

Change this:

```
<select type="text" name="user" class="form-control">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

To this:

```
<select name="user" class="form-control">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

There is no `type` attribute defined for the HTML `<select>` [tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp). Also you have to specify the `value` of the `<option>` tag which is being sent to the server

Comment: Thanks @Anton, now what what to know  is how to get the reference of value A or B,.. in my controller so that i can use it in my if condition.

Comment: This is why I asked what does `formData_one` contain in your controller? Now that the values of the `<option>`s are being sent to the server you should be able to retrieve them when binding the form

Comment: @Antony . what formData_one contains in my controller is this :  Customer_one data = formData_one.get();
        String message = Customer_one.save(data);       and every thing of my form is sent to the server . still an issue is to use the condition i specified above in my controller

Comment: What I mean is what are the individual properties of the `formData_one` object? If you now have access to the property `user` (as this is the name of the `<select>` field), you can get the value and do your comparison